# issue with DNS resolution

Tags: package-management, system-installation, upgrade, dns

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'internal.serevr'
Err:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'internal.serevr'
Err:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Could not resolve 'internal.serevr'
Err:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'internal.serevr
```

why this is showing 'internal.serevr'?

Comment: Is `v2gate.risenet.eu` set as your proxy?

Comment: may be, I am new to this, how can i remove this? just delete the /etc/apt/apt.conf? I can see this there Acquire::http::Proxy "http://v2gate.risenet.eu:8080";

Comment: You can remove `/etc/apt/apt.conf` **only** if the line you quoted is the **only** line in the file. Otherwise your `apt` will probably stop working. But this line didn't get there by accident. You must have set the proxy somewhere in the OS. Go to Settings app, select Network tab and check if proxy is configured there. If yes, turn it off.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: I am trying to upgrade the system to supported version and getting this error, will try to disable proxy

Comment: Yes, I am trying to upgrade my system to 18 and then 20 but this resolution error is getting. I checked /etc/environment file, proxy is not mentioned there

Comment: FYI:  Xenial is a 16.04 system, and upgrades to 18.04 and not Ubuntu Core 18.  Ubuntu releases using the *year* format are *snap* only and a different product to those using the *year.month* format.  What your question asks and what you say in comments currently differ, but your question is off-topic (it asks a *xenial* question; you've not edited it)